# How to specify getting local variable from a specific time frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

im trying to work out how to specify a local variable from a specific timeframe so i can use it later to trigger and alert

If possible without using request security

The normal macd and signal variables are working fine

here is what i have tried but they are not working ( im new to pinescript and have no idea what to do )

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="", shorttitle="", overlay=false ,format=format.price, precision=4)


macd                = slowMA - fastMA
signal              = ta.ema(macd, signalMACDlen)
macd15              = slowMA - fastMA,  timeframe.period ('15')
signal15            = (timeframe.period ='15'), ta.ema(macd, signalMACDlen)
macd5(timeframe.period ='5')     = slowMA - fastMA
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why don't you want to use the `security()` function?

Comment: i have already used 37 and if i use them for the variables i want i will have to remove some symbols ( setting up a loop alert )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an accurate value from another time frame request.security is needed. You can reduce the number of security calls by using your own function that returns multiple values for the same time frame.

````
my_function(parm1,parm2,parm3..parmn)=>
 {do stuff}
 [val1, val2, val3....valn]

[value1, value2, value3....valuen] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, my_function(parm1,parm2,parm3...parmn))```

// for example
f_get_all(src, fastlen, slowlen,siglen) =>
    [macdLine,signalLine,histLine]=  ta.macd(src, fastlen,slowlen,siglen)
    [rsii_]= ta.rsi(src, fastlen)

    [macdLine,signalLine,histLine,rsii_]



[macdLine15,signalline15,histLine15,rsii15]=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", f_get_fifteen_all(close,14,21))
````

Comment: Would this way work, not sure what you mean with the do stuff section :)     'code'  f_get_60_all(macd, signal, k, d, close) =>
    [macd60, signal60, k60, d60, close60]

[macd60, signal60, k60, d60, close60] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", f_get_60_all(macd, signal, k, d, close), barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on)

Comment: i updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

Would this work ?

```
f_get_fifteen_macd() => [MACD]
f_get_fifteen_signal() => [signal]
f_get_fifteen_k() => [k]
f_get_fifteen_d() => [d]

f_get_fifteen_all() =>
    [mac15] = f_get_fifteen_macd()
    [sig15] = f_get_fifteen_signal()
    [kli15] = f_get_fifteen_k()                                               
    [dli15] = f_get_fifteen_d()
request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", f_get_fifteen_all(), barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

'''